What greases are available for household use that don't contain persistent organic pollutants?
There are a few things I need to grease as part of home maintenance - sliding screen doors, windows, storm door closure mechanisms, machine/mower parts. I asked a couple of stores what to get and the options all had a lot of petrochemicals, in fact it seemed like all the options at my local home depot included PFPEs as an advertised feature. In a world with increasing awareness about "forever chemicals" like PFAS, it amazes me that this is even advertised, but I realize there's a reason PFAS are/were so useful and widely used. Even silicone-based greases, which I was pointed to as a healthier option, often had PFAS or other petrochemicals on their SDS when I checked them.
For household applications that are not so demanding, what are options that are not importing 'forever' pollutants into my home and habitat? I feel like there's a whole type of grease that I'm just missing or asking the wrong question about. Like if a child might scoop up some grease on a screen door part, what is a relatively safe option that still works effectively?

If traditional paraffin wax is unacceptable, perhaps beeswax will do. Expect either one to attract dirt.

Some lubricants do pose an environmental hazard, such as motor oils, but there often is no satisfactory substitute. For a wooden drawer, certainly, use soap or paraffin wax (which is a harmless petrochemical.). Do the best you can, and recycle lubricants used in large amounts, suc as the previously-mentioned motor oil.

I can't think of  single place in my house where I need enough grease that there would be an amount to ingest.  Food grade oil and grease are non-toxic, but don't expect oil companies to share your concerns with chemicals.

Lubricants have to be chosen to match their intended use and environment. Many things that work well enough at room temperature on clean surfaces wouldn't survive in/on the mower. You need to look at specific cases... and consider whether there actually is enough released to be worth worrying about.

That would be food grade grease.
I'm gonna go out on a limb and say... if you're letting your kid scoop up grease from a sliding door track the problem is not with the grease ingredients and forever chemicals.

It's not about me letting anyone do anything. That's not a current scenario for me. What I'm asking about is what @clvrmnky points out: small amounts build up over time, and many recommended/standard products have bioaccumulating toxins in them.

Food grade grease is certainly an answer. I didn't see that for these kinds of non-food applications and I'm not sure if they're interchangeable, but it sounds like they can be. For that matter, it sounds like beeswax works, it just might attract crud and need more frequently cleaning (I guess with hot water?) and reapplication. What I'm looking for are simpler/relatively accessible nontoxic solutions, and I gave one example use case.
